# How to directly store a hash of model with has_many relationship without using .new (without initializing object) in Rails Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Suppose I have these models in rails.

**ParentObject Model**

```
class ParentObject
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :child_objects, autosave: true, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :child_objects

  field :p_test_field, type: String
  field :p_test_field_two, type: String
end
```

**ChildObject Model**

```
class ChildObject < ParentObject
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :parent_object

  field :c_test_field, type: String
  field :c_test_field_two, type: String
end
```

Now to save data I use this code.

```
@parent_object = ParentObject.new(parent_object_params)
@parent_object.child_objects_attributes = {"0" => {:c_test_field => "test2"}}
@parent_object.save
```

So that is how data is saved. Now I want to save data using a hash without using the .new method , i.e. without initializing the object. How can that be done? I just want to store from a hash which has values for child object as well as parent object. What would be the format for that hash? I mean I don't even have a parent_object_id

**My primary object is to batch insert the data into parent and child object no matter how.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hash should contain an array of `child_objects_attributes` hashes

```
{
  :p_test_field => "attr test one",
  :p_test_field_two => "attr test two",
  ...
  :child_objects_attributes => [
    { :c_test_field => "test 1" }
  ]
}
```

With this calling `ParentObject.create(hash)` would create both objects and their associations.

See https://mongoid.github.io/en/mongoid/docs/nested_attributes.html

Comment: It should be `child_objects_attributes`.